# RAPI version of RegFlushKey method?

Tags: c#, windows-ce, activesync, rapi

I searched a lot and could not find something useful.
I am writing a config utility running on desktop PC and modifies registry settings of connected WINCE 6.0 device. It is achieved using RAPI/RAPI2 with activesync installation on desktop PC. Changed registry settings are no longer exists on device after rebooting. Googling  guided to use "RegFlushKey" method. But I found noway to use this function from RAPI.
Please suggest some way to make registry settings persist after reboot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific [RAPI function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa921197.aspx) for RegFlushKey.  Your best bet is to create a RAPI DLL with your own CeRegFlushKey call in it, push it down (CeCreateFile and CeWriteFile work well for this) and call [CeRapiInvoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa917422.aspx).  Altrnately just write an app that makes the call, push it down and use CeCreateProcess to execute it.

Comment: Is there any other way to solve this problem apart from the way you are suggesting? From desktop app, Can I call functions of coredll.dll OR any other DLL which contains RegFlushKey definition?

Comment: If there were another way, I would have suggested it.  Pushing down an app then running it seems pretty simple and lightweight.  A RAPI DLL would be extensible.  Both are pretty straightforward.